# Can the definite article be used with special days or holidays?

Tags: usage

Is it possible to use the definite article with holidays and special days like Flag Day and Valentine's Day? For instance, are "the Flag Day", "the Valentine's Day", or "the Christmas" correct?

I'm wondering because people can use either "the earth" or "Earth" and be grammatically correct with either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It's not standard English, first of all. Holidays are usually considered to be names in and of themselves, so adding an article doesn't make sense.

Second, a number of holidays are possessives. *Valentine's Day*, *Mothers' Day*, [*St. Crispin's Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Crispin%27s_Day), etc. One does not add an article to possessive forms.

*Earth* as opposed to *the earth* is a different situation. Our world is *the earth*. However, in English the term *the earth* has been borrowed to be the name of our world as well, *Earth*. (There is the additional confusion that dirt can also be called *earth*.) It is because of this potential for ambiguity that science fiction writers will often use the term *Terra* for our world, and *Sol* for our sun.

(Consider Washington DC, which is served by an airport named Washington-Dulles International. One could say "I am going to the airport", or "I am going to Washington Dulles International". One would not say "I am going to the Dulles".)

That all being said, while it is NOT standard English, it is not uncommon to use  inappropriate articles for humourous effect. I frequently make references to "The Google", and I can imagine students talking about "going home for the Christmas".

Comment: So if I don't intend to be funny, it's outright wrong to use articles with holidays, right? I keep using articles at the beginning of my sentences and it makes me sound funny. How can I avoid these awkward artcles?

Comment: If you're not intending to be funny, then no, it is not appropriate to use articles with holidays. As for how to avoid awkward articles at the beginning of sentences, that might be more of a question for the [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). The best thing I can think of is hard work: Review what you write before publishing it, and specifically look at sentence beginnings for inappropriate articles. It is not easy and it is not fun, but it works.

Comment: What about when I'm talking to people? I tend to throw in random "the" and "a". Another question on writing-is is correct if i write (or say, even) the earth day without capitalizing anything?

Comment: If you write "the earth day" then you have made two mistakes: including the article, and not capitalizing a proper name.  Say "the" when you are talking about a specific object that you are referring to by its generic name ("the desk", "the chair"); do not say "the" when you are referring to something by its unique, individual name ("Google", "Fred").

Comment: @jess: "Outright wrong" is a strong way of saying it. You might see an article in front of a holiday, when the holiday is being used as an adjective, as opposed to a reference to the holiday itself. So, for example, you might see,  _the Thanksgiving weekend, the Christmas season, a President's Day sale, a Valentine's Day peak_, etc.

Comment: @J.R. A point which might help learner's understand why it is acceptable in these cases is that the article refers to the other word in the sentence; *the weekend*, *the season*, *a sale*, *a peak*.

Comment: What about when you're referring to a particular Christmas?  For example, I might talk about *the Christmas of '92*, and I think that doing so is standard.

Comment: @snailboat: Keep in mind that that's a slightly different situation. In that case, you have moved from an abstract concept of *Christmas Day* to a specific concept of *one specific day that happens to have been a Christmas*. Nobody would refer to me as "the Jonathan" (aside from humourous effect,) but it would be entirely correct to refer to me as "the Jonathan who lives at [location]".

Comment: @JonathanGarber That's a good point, though there *are* [other situations](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3004/230) when proper nouns can be converted to common nouns.