# Definite article before name of languages

Tags: definite-article

Should I use the definite article before name of languages?

- (the?) Persian language
- (the?) German language
- (the?) Arabic language
- (the?) Russian language
- (the?) English language

Some language name may also refer to other things, so you need *language* word after their name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The article goes with *language*, so the following work as noun phrases:

> English
>
> *the* English *language*

The following doesn't usually work as a noun phrase referring to the English language.  It would more likely be interpreted as referring to the English *people*:

> *＊*the English

Take a look at the following example sentences:

> **1a.** I speak English.
>
> **1b.** *？*I speak the English language.
>
> **1c.** *＊*I speak the English.
>
> **2a.** English is a beautiful thing.
>
> **2b.** The English language is a beautiful thing.
>
> **2c.** *＊*The English is a beautiful thing.

Examples **1c** is wrong.  Example **2c** is wrong in most situations.  Example **1b** sounds strange; we usually only say "the English language" when speaking about the language in the abstract or as a whole.  Saying "English" always works, though it doesn't always sound as nice:

> **3a.** By some estimates, there are over a million words in the English language.
>   **3b.** By some estimates, there are over a million words in English.

Both examples are acceptable, but example **3a** sounds better.

Of course, there are other situations where you'd use an article with bare *English*, such as in the phrase *the English of Shakespeare*, but you can do that with any proper noun (see [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3004/230)).  And if you're using *English language* as a modifier, it doesn't need an article because it's not functioning as a noun.  In the following example, *English language* is inserted into the noun phrase *a Q&A site* as a modifier:

> **4.** Stack Exchange is an English language Q&A site.

The article *an* belongs to *site*, not to *English*, *language*, or *Q&A*.

---

*＊ means I think this utterance is unacceptable.*
*？ means I think this utterance is questionable, but not as bad as those marked with ＊.*

Comment: The New Yorker routinely uses "the" with language names and without the word "language" in sentences like "Translated, from the Russian, by XYZ". Is there an explanation to that? For example: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/06/13/the-russian-professor

Answer (score 1):

As [@FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/definite-article-before-name-of-languages#comment12551_7788) said, you don't normally use *the* and *language* when speaking of a language. For example, this is an excerpt from the Wikipedia article about [Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language):

> Persian is an Iranian language within the Indo-Iranian branch of the Indo-European languages.

*Iranian language* and *Indo-European language* identify the language family of Persian.

Similar description is given for [Russian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language):

> Russian is a Slavic language spoken primarily in Russia, Belarus, Ukraine, Kazakhstan, and Kyrgyzstan.

The fact you are talking of a language is understood from the context. The fact *Italian* could mean the language or a person from Italy doesn't mean you need to say *the Italian language* when you speak of the language; that is not what English native speakers do, in the same way English native speakers don't normally say *American person*.

The following sentences are perfectly understood from English native speakers, without the need to replace *Italian* with *the Italian language*.

> I know Italian enough to talk with Italians and be understood.

> I can read Italian, but I don't speak it well.

Answer (score 0):

The definite and indefinite articles are used in front of languages when they refer to a variety of that language:

> The English spoken in Canada differs from that spoken in the U.S. only
> in pronunciation.

Or to its use in a particular situation or medium:

> The English (used) in that article leaves much to be desired.