# Should I use 'the' before language names?

Tags: definite-article

In following sentences, should I use **the**:

- Persian is sweet.
- (the) Persian language is sweet.
- (the) Contemporary Persian language is sweet.
- (the) Contemporary Persian is sweet.

Comment: It's not the question you're asking, but "sweet" is an unusual adjective to apply to a language.

Comment: @starsplusplus I "sweet" is used exclusively to describe the Persian language. Google it! It is realy sweet! Say some thing in Persian to taste it.

Comment: I Googled sweet and Persian and didn't get anything. What do you suggest I Google?

Comment: @starsplusplus `"persian is sweet"` use quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

Before *Persian language*, yes, you should use it.

But if you use the name of the language on its own, you do not!

"The Persian is sweet" refers to a specific *person* of Persian extraction, not to the language (or actually, it could be a cat in this case!).

Comment: Thanks, what about two last ones?

Comment: Same thing. Whether you use Persian **language**, Contemporary Persian **language** or contemporary often-used sweet-sounding fluent Persian **language**, you still omit _the_ when you mention _language_, and you use _the_ when you just use _Persian_ :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, to answer it precisely...

> Persian is sweet - Okay, what's her name? (So, here the *Persian* will serve the same as *American*. 
>   (the) Persian language is sweet - Of course, it's a sweet language. 
>   (the) Contemporary Persian language is sweet - True, the latest words and literary work for the language makes the modern Persian language even sweeter. 
>   (the) Contemporary Persian is sweet - oops! the contemporary person does not sound natural!

A further good read [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/definite-article-before-name-of-languages).