# Why is the definite article "the" used before some dances and with others not?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article, generic-noun-phrases

I crossed with two sentences:

- Tango is a partner dance and social dance that originated in the
  1880s along to the Río de la Plata.
- How to dance the Tango.

So, I got very confused because the definite article "the" is not used before proper nouns usually, and "Tango" is a proper noun. Thereby, why does one sentence use "the" and the other not? Is there any rule in this case?

I think that the same happens with the dance named Waltz.

Furthermore, why with some dances, it's not used any article, such as Ballet, gayageum and samulnori?

EDIT: It's been recommended this source:[“the top levels of government” -- why not "of THE government"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/the-top-levels-of-government-why-not-of-the-government). Nevertheless, I think this question is more related to the generic topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“the top levels of government” -- why not "of THE government"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/the-top-levels-of-government-why-not-of-the-government) I know the title seems like it might not be relevant, but there is a very good answer to that question that applies to your question as well.

Comment: I don't think that really addresses the same question.  That answer explains (very well) why/how in some cases an article is *left out* when using *common nouns* which usually use one, but it does not answer why an article would be *added* to *proper nouns* when they normally do not use one, which is what's being asked here.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know the answer to this (I may have to do some research), but I will note that it's not just limited to "Tango" and "Waltz", I believe the use of "the" is generally used with *all* named dances.  I think this may have to do with the fact that they are proper nouns, but they are also a generic term that can have concrete instances (i.e. "the Tango" is the dance form in general, while "a Tango" is a specific instance of somebody performing that dance).

Comment: @Foogod I think that you've made your point, I'm going to explain it just in case. In this context of dances, it's acceptable to use articles because there's an implied noun:                Would you like to dance the Tango (dance)? In this case, the article "the" is used in a generic structure to give a generalization to refer to the instances when one performs that dance. So, in the first sentence of my comment, one can say: Tango is a..(Using it as a proper noun). Otherwise, The Tango (dance) is a.... (Using the generic structure to generalize, i.e giving like a prototypical instance).

Comment: @Foogod And with the article "a" is also possible to use the generic structure called "Indefinite Generic", such as: A Tango (dance) is danced by a couple. But you cannot say: A Tango can give you more control over your body. You say: The Tango.....(definite generic). Furthermore, as you say, it's also possible to use the article "a" to mean one instance: Darling, would you like a Tango (dance) with me?.                                                So, I think that is what you mean, and it has a good argument. Do you agree?

Comment: However, some dances never use any article (like Ballet), so what I just explained (if it's true) can't be applied in certain cases, perhaps without any reason.

Comment: I think the distinction with "Ballet" is that it is actually not a *named dance* (lke Tango or Waltz), but rather a *style of performance*.  There are many different ballets involving a wide variety of dance moves in all manner of choreography, unlike the Tango or Waltz which are defined by a specific set of movements (in particular ways) that make them that specific thing. (so there are many different ballets, but arguably only one Tango)

Comment: This question and answer may also be helpful: [Definite article before name of languages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7788/9161)

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the research, I read the two links, but I think it would be more understandable to take it as a generic topic. Anyway, I didn't know that with some words you can omit the article if they are already definite and that saying the English language carries a more abstract concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue this.

You need the article because the word dance is implied.

- The tango is hard to master. [implied: The tango is a dance.]
- The samba is not. [implied: same as above].
- The waltz is not so hard to learn. [same thing].

All the above are dances and I would use the article. I would always use a the in front of any specific dance. However, not for the music associated with it.

- Samba [music] is hard to play.
- Tango [music] is great to learn.

Ballet is different because it is not "a dance". In fact, it functions like a proper noun, like, for example, classical music.

But beware with ballet. Aficionados sometimes call it "The dance" in English and this is because of the French language where generalities are preceded by an article. That is a tradition and not a grammar issue.