# Is 'A dead [Proper Noun]' okay?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, proper-nouns

I've read it at many places. I'm not sure whether they were authentic sources. But in any case, is it grammatical to say 'A dead [proper noun]'?

Say,

> ***A*** dead Michael Jackson

I mean ***an indefinite article*** for a proper noun?

[Here are [some results;](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20dead%20michael%20jackson%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22a%20dead%20michael%20jackson%22&tbm=nws) kindly consider the relevant ones]

---

[I only had asked this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/under-what-circumstances-does-a-proper-noun-of-a-person-take-the-definite-arti) but then the explanation in the selected answer is specific. It talks about *making difference* between one and many with the same name. Here, it's **not** the case.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But I've come across sentences like "A **dying** Micheal Jackson...."

Comment: I think a better question may be, rather than "Is it grammatical", "When is it grammatical".

Comment: I agree with @Dam. Language is flexible and many utterances are allowed to exist, but that doesn't mean they're allowed to exist in **every** context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the indefinite article in "Their campaign mounts in fury as a free Europe crumbles"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75141/why-the-indefinite-article-in-their-campaign-mounts-in-fury-as-a-free-europe-cr)

Comment: Note that other adjectives can be used this way too - for example, "[a young Michael Jackson](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20young%20michael%20jackson%22)"

Comment: A dead MJ, a young MJ, a relaxed MJ, a broke MJ, a famous MJ, an accused MJ, a frazzled MJ... These are each possible real MJs that we can reference. The same for another proper noun: a free Europe, a united Europe, a panicked Europe, a dead Europe, a living Europe, a frazzled Europe...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In a crime novel you might say:

**A dead ______A________ would afford the ____B____ syndicate an opportunity to consolidate its power in the city's south side, while the  ___A____ family were dealing with the power vacuum.**

Where "A" might be the name of the crime boss in a competing family.

There, **a** marks a hypothetical.

A newspaper photograph of crowds standing on the street as a funeral cortège went by might have this caption:

**A dead _____________ is mourned by adoring fans**.

There, it would have a scene-setting rhetorical function.

Comment: Is there a problem with the formatting in your Q? I don't get it :(

Comment: What's this? Paraphrasing needed!

Comment: What needs paraphrasing?